# ini Path editing in in text

Tags: powershell, replace, ini, backslash, slash

I made a litle script wath change Paths in ini files what are in a folder and in the subfolder of the foldr. So my Problem is i see there are Paths with `\` `D:\example\` and Path with `/` `F:/example/`. My script change only `\` and i trie to include `/` but i fail. Can you help me?

Here my Script

```
<# here i create a new folder with the folder dialog #>
Ad-Type-AssemblyName
syste,-windows.Forms
$browser = New-Object system.windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$browser.Description " Make A New Folder
$null = $browser.showDialog()
$browser = $NewPath

<# here i select a folder what i want to copy with the folder dialog #>
Ad-Type-AssemblyName
syste,-windows.Forms
$browser = New-Object system.windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$browser.Description " Make A New Folder
$null = $browser.showDialog()
$browser = $OldPath

<# Here i copy the old in the new folder #>
Copy-Item $OldPath\* $NewPath -recurse

<# Here i replace the old Paths with backslashes in the ini files (they are in the text of the ini file) with the new #>

$ChangePath = $OldPath
$iniFile = Get-ChildItem -Path "$NewPath/* include *.ini -recurse
ForEach($file in $iniFile){
   (Get-Content $file)-replace [regex]::Escape($ChangePath),($NewPath) | Set-Content - Path $file.FullName

 <# this uper the comment work but now come what doesnt work #>
 <# here i try to replace all paths in the text of the ini file with a normal slash "/" #>

$changePath2 = $OldPath
($changePath2 -replace [regex]::Escape ('\'),('/'))
$NewPath = $NewPath
($NewPath2 -replace [regex]::Escape ('\'),('/'))
$iniFile2 = Get-ChildItem -Path "$NewPath/* include *.ini -recurse
ForEach($file2 in $iniFile2){
   (Get-Content $file2)-replace [regex]::Escape($ChangePath2),($NewPath2) | Set-Content - Path $file2.FullName
```

This doesnt work and when it would work it need more time because i must read all ini Files in the Folder and the subfolder. Is there any way to do it one time and not in two? It would great when you cann help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use PowerShell's `-replace` and escape the backslash. Example: `"\\\" -replace "\\","/"` returns `///`